# jQuery how to get src of each childern

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I log into console src value of each image inside .item element?

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/058c4b8713460d873a8554fb512a2e331d8cd4c91f377d2387a01810.png?b7a570e62751fb0a6f6c7d9dd741e442" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/fa9e3865d1aaab0ff51f1b61ec6d380d8a7769e9e07d9bb0aee4a54f.png?907dbf65448243f0f18facb579b927a6" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

With my try I get only undefined.

```
var address = $("#wrap").find(".item img").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('src');
  console.log(address);
});
```

Here is codepen as well http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKYjma?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this inside the function:

```
console.log($(this).attr('src'));
```

You're not doing anything with `$(this).attr('src');` on the second line. Logging `address` is returning `undefined` because it is simply not defined. You can also remove the `var address =` from the first line, because I guess you're just trying to execute a function. I think your code should look like this:

```
$("#wrap").find(".item img").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: `each` doesn't return anything so `address` will be undefined. Not clear why it is being used

Comment: I know ;) edited my comment, was too fast with answering to even notice that

Comment: yeah...update makes explanation more understandable for OP